# ¿Cómo obtener información de varias columnas una sola fila con SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente estructura de una tabla: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer es que un usuario especifico me muestre toda la informacion en una sola columna, es decir el resultado seria asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea de como podría hacer esto?

Comment: Buenas Luis, ¿Qué has intentado? para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 1):

Haciendo un select básico de esta manera debería darte lo que buscas. Simplemente cambia **nombre_tabla** por el nombre de la tabla que estes utilizando.

```
    SELECT id_user, question1_a1s1, question2_a1s1, question3_a1s1, question1_a2s1, question2_a2s1 FROM nombre_tabla
```

Añades los campos que necesitas y luego pones el nombre de la tabla.

Si además quieres mostrar solamente la información para el usuario con la id 152 utiliza un `WHERE`.

```
SELECT id_user, question1_a1s1, question2_a1s1, question3_a1s1, question1_a2s1, question2_a2s1 FROM nombre_tabla WHERE id = 153;
```

Comment: Esa es buena idea, si lo había intentando pero al querer mostrarlo en php no me daba el resultado de la segunda fila